# Azure issues when I try to acces to VPN

Tags: azure, account, organization

In my company I use VPN service and when I try to connect to my account (that is different from my organization) it gives me error because it automatically log in with the other account. So I need to go on Azure portal, sign out everywhere from my organization account and then make the access to the VPN. I'm not so expert of Azure but I was asking if there is a way to not automatically connect to my organization account and that gives me the chance to chose without signing out everywhere. I tried to look at role and administration but I didn't understand so much. Can you guys please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you have a personal Azure account and a company Azure login.

I have the same situation. What I do personally is use a different browser for each. For example, our company has standardized on Chrome so I only use Chrome for the company Azure account. That way I don't have to try to log out the company account, hope it's logged out everywhere, etc.
I use a different browser, like Firefox or Edge, for my personal Azure account.

So pick one browser for use only for your company and remove the saved login for your personal account. Then for the different browser for your personal account, log in with your personal account and remove or don't add your company account.

That should solve the problem. Let me know if that works.